# How to remove unused versions of Wine in snap

Tags: apt, wine, snap, disk-usage

I'm trying to clear memory on my hard drive, and I found multiple wine installations under snap folder, which total to more than 10Gb, 10% of hard drive space.

```
> snap list

wine-platform-3-stable        3.0.4                             14     latest/stable    mmtrt           -
wine-platform-5-stable        5.0.3                             18     latest/stable    mmtrt           -
wine-platform-6-stable        6.0.4                             19     latest/stable    mmtrt           -
wine-platform-7-devel-core20  7.21                              23     latest/stable    mmtrt           -
wine-platform-runtime         v1.0                              318    latest/stable    mmtrt           -
wine-platform-runtime-core20  v1.0                              47     latest/stable    mmtrt           -
```

One or two of them may be in use by software I have installed (I have still one thing installed with wine, maybe something more). Is there any way I can remove the wine-platforms that are not in use? Is it safe simply to remove all but the newest stable version? I imagine that they are from various software that has been installed and removed that relied on wine.

wine --version prints says that command line is using v3, not the newest one though.

```
> wine --version
wine-3.0 (Ubuntu 3.0-1ubuntu1)
```

Any help appreciated. Extra: If there is no way to tell which ones any software is using, I think that the needed software is using only the command line option which is the version 3.0 one. Is it safe to remove the others? Can I also remove the 'runtime' folders?

Comment: There is an easy way to tell which of these wine-platform snaps are dependencies: Simply try to uninstall each one: `sudo snap remove <name>`. If another installed snap requires the platform, then snapd will refuse and will instead tell you exactly which snaps require that platform snap.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's very comforting! Did this and found out that none of the software I was suspecting depended on snap wine, but one did depend on wine that was installed outside snap. Great help, thanks!